# Can I use flutter to create an index on firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the following flutter code to query firestore which orders the data using the field timestamp.

```
var results = Firestore.instance.collection('post').orderBy('timestamp').getDocuments().then((value) {
  var list = value.documents;
  return list.map((doc) {
    return doc.documentID;
  }).toList();
});
```

When I run this code, it throws the below exception saying an index is required:

> W/Firestore(31110): (21.3.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(app/jQH7Fp9xCZWYiqZRe7lE/post where readAccess array_contains_any [WzKImODx6WYVqdSW3D9Az3xrUnM2, PUBLIC] order by -timestamp, -**name**) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/....

The exception even comes with a nice link. When opening that link, a nice UI pops up giving me the ability to create the index, with just a simple click:

[image]

Question: simple as the above may seem, I'm not very happy with this. I prefer to be able to create the index from fluttercode. In code I'm looking for something like the below:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('post').API-TO-CREATE-INDEX('timestamp');
```

Does it exist? Please advise. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to create an index from client apps.  You have three main choices:

1. Clicking the link you already saw.
2. Using the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#use_the_firebase_cli) to deploy the index from the command line.
3. Using the [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/indexes/composite/create) to also deploy from the command line

See also the [documentation on managing indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing).